# Utilizing UITouch tapCount in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, multitasking, uitouch

I am trying to count screen touches and am using the UITouch tapCount to do so.  I need to be able to continue to count touches when the app enters background mode.  I will be utilizing location services so I know I can keep the app alive, but I'm not sure if it is possible to continue to utilize tapCount.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible since your view is no longer on screen to receive touches.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Once the app goes into background mode - the screen no longer belongs to the app - but the home screen (Or whatever other app is on screen) - also, due to the way apps on iOS devices are sandboxed - this would be crossing that line.. 
Why do you need to register taps outside of the app?

Comment: The need is similar to a pedometer that counts up and down movements registered by the accelerometer while running in the background (as most pedometer apps do).  The difference is that I am trying to count interactions with the phone during significant location changes to monitor phone usage.

Comment: Then definitely not - you're stepping out of the "Sandbox" that Apple creates around all apps. This is just not even remotely possible. Find another way to achieve your end goal or move onto another feature / idea.